# Two copy text buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I've discovered how to use the copy text button for now line, but tried to modify the script to use multiple buttons with multiple text boxes. 
Firstly, the only way I can see is if I duplicate the script, altering variables, which is too much code.
Secondly, what I have written only copies the last instance

```js
function myFunction() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
      copyText.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
        var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput2");
      copyText.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      
      var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
      tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
        var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip2");
      tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
    }
    
    function outFunc() {
      var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
      tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
        var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip2");
      tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
    }
```

```css
.tooltip {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 140px;
      background-color: #555;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      bottom: 150%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -75px;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -5px;
      border-width: 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
    
    <div class="tooltip">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
      <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
      Copy text
      </button>
    </div>
    <p>
    <input type="text" value="Hello World 2" id="myInput2">
    
    <div class="tooltip">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
      <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip2">Copy to clipboard</span>
      Copy text
      </button>
    </div>
```

There aren't any errors as such, but the above script only copies the second instance for both buttons

Comment: Yes, because you copy the second one right after the first one without using it. You're using copyText and tooltip variables for both cases. Do you mean to seperate them?

Comment: I looks like you are copying `myInput1` and immediately copy `myInput2` which will replace the contents of the first input in the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

This section is the problem:

```
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
copyText.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput2");
copyText.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
```

You are copying the text to clipboard from both input elements. Instead you could use an attribute on both buttons to point to the input element from which the text should be copied.

For example,

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" data-target="myInput" onmouseout="outFunc()">
```

Here, `myFunction(this)` carries the reference to clicked button in the event handler function, and `data-target="myInput"` points to the text element from which the text should be copied.

Now "myFunction" function just needs to use these info to put needed text to clipboard. Here's working demo:

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  var targetElementID = elem.getAttribute("data-target");
  var copyText = document.getElementById(targetElementID);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
   

  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
    var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip2");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
    var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip2");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" data-target="myInput" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>
<p>
<input type="text" value="Hello World 2" id="myInput2">

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" data-target="myInput2" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip2">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect - Been away a while a first Monday back... Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is an issue with tooltips: they do not displayed when the buttons are hovered and on click, both display the tooltip text: "Copied: Hello World Copy text".

Comment: @MaximeLaunois Yeah, I didn't copy the CSS because that was conflicting with Stack snippets. The HTML and JS are enough to answer anyway. :)